# Triying to get absolute URL is not outputting the right path?

Tags: php, server, path

My brain stopped working, I bet is a really simple solution but i can't get to it, i tried scraping moving around the \ but it keeps echo'ng just "/". I want to get this to use it on my CSS, and JS files so they get loaded after url rewrite.

```
$domain = "http://". $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/"; 
echo $domain;
//echo just "/"
```

I tried also with:

```
$domain = $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME']. "://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/";
```

same result...

Comment: reads like the `$_SERVER` vars  are not set .. see what you have available with `print_r($_SERVER);`

Comment: What does `var_dump($_SERVER)` show?

Comment: They re actually set, it gives me an array full of data. I don't get it, why it does show up only /

Comment: It 's pretty weird if i try to output "http :// localhost" it echoes / if i remove the ":" or one slash it outputs the full string.

Comment: view source, not via browser

Comment: i did it via source code, and i get all the attributes

Comment: if all you say is true, this simply seems impossible, sorry.

Comment: I know! i know it's not possible, i dont get it. Everything seems alright, it's getting i don't know commenting or something like that because of the double slash, tbh I don't get it.